# CSS Evenly Space Images That Are Tiled

Tags: html, css

This question is different I think from other evenly space questions as they are in a tiled format and try as I might, I'm trying to have maybe 1 or 2 pixels of white space between each image.. I can't get them to appear 'evenly spaced' from eachother, any kind of margin I use ends up creating extra space along lines, more so than others - here is the project visually:

[image]

[image]

Please Note: The gap between the images is just what it is, a gap between two images, it's not one image with that being the space on the website. thanks.

Code wise this if the layout, it's squarespace and does have long class names etc, but the setup is nothing too fancy html.

I've kept it simple by just adding the code of two of the images.

I have tried margins, padding and several other techniques but as I said I must be missing a technique to it. Thanks so much if you can help.

Kind regards,
Dale.

```
<div id="grid" data-collection-id="5d4001b0fcf930000104fb44" class="sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns sqs-frontend-overlay-editor-widget-host" style="height: 6042px;">
  
  
    <div class="item sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide sqs-active-slide" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_300" data-type="image" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 512px; height: 768px;" overlaydelay="683">
      <a href="/flora/" data-dynamic-load="" data-dynamic-receiver="#detail_5d485397aa43b00001c13f10" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_658">
        <div class="wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_909">
          <div class="project-title" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_908">
            <h2>FLORA</h2>
            <h3>— view —</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <img class="thumbnail loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5d4acb10fbcad1000131ec78/1565021165268/" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5d4acb10fbcad1000131ec78/1565021165268/" data-image-dimensions="2500x3750" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-resolution="1500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5d4acb10fbcad1000131ec78/1565021165268/?format=1500w">
          <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5d4acb10fbcad1000131ec78/1565021165268/?format=original"></noscript>
        
      </a>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <div class="item sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide slide-stretched" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_302" data-type="image" style="top: 0px; left: 512px; width: 513px; height: 341px;" overlaydelay="749">
      <a href="/new-gallery-3/" data-dynamic-load="" data-dynamic-receiver="#detail_5c6c2d80e5e5f0425f12359f" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_664">
        <div class="wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2180">
          <div class="project-title" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2179">
            <h2 id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2178">SPLASH</h2>
            <h3 id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2205">— view —</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <img class="thumbnail loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5c6c2e9f4192029c21f9efc9/1550593684993/" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5c6c2e9f4192029c21f9efc9/1550593684993/" data-image-dimensions="2500x1667" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-resolution="1500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5c6c2e9f4192029c21f9efc9/1550593684993/?format=1500w">
          <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5c6c2e9f4192029c21f9efc9/1550593684993/?format=original"></noscript>
        
      </a>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <div class="item sqs-gallery-design-autocolumns-slide slide-stretched" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_304" data-type="image" style="top: 341px; left: 512px; width: 513px; height: 768px;" overlaydelay="738">
      <a href="/vista-1/" data-dynamic-load="" data-dynamic-receiver="#detail_5e6b7ab66738445292e92162" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_670">
        <div class="wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2265">
          <div class="project-title" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2264">
            <h2 id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2311">VISTA</h2>
            <h3 id="yui_3_17_2_1_1594055977667_2309">— view —</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <img class="thumbnail loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5e6b7b88a49df07438882f6b/1584102280234/" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5e6b7b88a49df07438882f6b/1584102280234/" data-image-dimensions="2500x3750" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-resolution="1500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5e6b7b88a49df07438882f6b/1584102280234/?format=1500w">
          <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5873baef5016e16ec2d0f471/t/5e6b7b88a49df07438882f6b/1584102280234/?format=original"></noscript>
        
      </a>
    </div
  
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code you're using so we can try to help you.

Comment: You need to set height width for that images eg. 300px height 300px width & margin 10px